# awk for a match located at nth row of a tsv file (large, unknown n)

Tags: bash, awk

I have a large tsv file over 100 mil rows and am using awk function to print 3rd field if the 1st field matches certain number. The first field is strictly monotonically increasing along rows with certain gaps. For example, if I want to find the row where its 1st field that matches 7, then I start awk from 7th row backwards and stop if found. This will make the process speed up. Is there a way to jump in to nth row and do a awk from there, while not going through the whole loop to get to nth row?

The options I have thought:

1) Parsing the data for certain number of rows with

```
tail -n+1000000 SearchInfo.tsv | head -n10
```

trick and do a awk there.

2) Using NR:

```
awk -F $'\t' 'NR>1000000&&$1==matchnumber {print $3}'
```

seems very slow.

[Sample data]

```
1 10 3 4   
4 10 533 6  
5 1 10 1  
7 19 10 11  
...  
10101110 30 15 91
```

[Goal]
find the row that has 100101110 in a fast, efficient way.

[Expected output]
    15

---

[Resolved]
Below seems to do the work, but it still takes about 10 seconds in OS X terminal. Going to use SQLite instead as recommended.

```
head -n 10101110 file | tail -r | awk -F $'\t' '$1 == 10101110 {print $3; exit}'
```

As msw suggested, the below seems fast; my own goal had to find the match backward from nth row. If the user has a good information of the expected row of match (e.g. shortly after 1000000th row), then below seems as a faster solution.

```
sed -e '1,10000000d' file | awk -F $'\t' '$1 == 10101110 {print $3; exit}'
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: You have a text database with over 1 million rows? Use a real Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk processes the lines one at a time, so you can be sure that when searching for N it will run your script <= N times on the whole dataset, provided you exit once the match is made.

Beyond that, you might expect that

1. the file is large enough that loading it into memory is slow *and/or*
2. you expect it more likely for the number to appear at the end of the first N lines of file

For 1. I would use

```
head -n N file | awk -f script number=N
```

though for large N, clearly, you may end up loading the whole file anyway.

For 2. I would use

```
head -n N file | tac | awk -f script number=N
```

where `tac` is "`cat` backwards" (this will also take time, and may slow the operation down overall).

```
# script
($1 == number) { print $3; exit }
```

as in your question, but with an early exit.

From your description, using `tail` seems like a mistake, as there is no guarantee N is not on the first line of the file for any N - but you know your data better than I do.

If you're searching for/operating on a large set of rows, you might want a solution entirely in one awk script: load the data and perform all of your operations on it in one execution.

Comment: Using tac along with head is a smart way! OS X terminal does not have tac so used _tail -r_ instead.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If your first field is strictly monotonic (i.e. your matched number can occur only once), then it' simple:

```
awk '{ if ($1 == matchnumber) { print $3; exit; } }'
```

However, if it can occur multiple times, then do this:

```
awk '
BEGIN { 
    prev = 0
}

{ 
   if ($1 == matchnumber) { 
        print $3;
    } else if (prev == matchnumber) {
        exit
    };
    prev = $1;
}'
```

Comment: maybe I did not emphasize that I did not want to loop through every line by using awk, since I had a huge file.

Comment: @villybyun You mentioned that only in the title but from the problem description it's not clear that it's what you really want. You only said that the numbers are increasing monotonically. Let's say you are searching for number 10'000'000. How can you be sure that it's not the first element? If you have a so huge amount of data, do as msw said: use a real database. For example SQLite is file based and you can probably control it from command line too.

Comment: Yes, I should have been more clear. I did not have experience dealing with big data and thought bash would be just faster. I will try SQLite as you have recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I made a 2'000'000 row text file and on a not so fast laptop, the command

```
sed -e '1,1000000d' 2mlllion-rows.txt
```

completed in 0.230 seconds. The command says **d**elete the first through millionth rows, thus the output was only the second million rows. You can pipe that into awk and incur almost no chop-time penalty.

Comment: This command is indeed great, but when I pipe the result into awk, sed reads even after awk finds its match. The below is how I used it. Is there a way to early exit sed if awk find its match?

sed -e '1,50d' file | awk -F $'\t' '$1 == 250001 {print $4; exit}'

Comment: When awk exits, it closes the pipe and write() calls made by sed generate an SIGPIPE signal which kills the sed process. I'd need to see compelling evidence that sed continued reading after awk terminated. I just ran a test myself and found exactly what I expected.

Comment: You are indeed right. I checked it in the wrong way.